# Auth0 Laravel seed project. Always unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel, auth0

Trying to use Postman to test my app.

Got an `access_token` and `id_token` by posting to /oauth/ro using a `test` use I created on Auth0's dashboard.

Now in the seed project there's this route `/api/protected` and I'm trying to do a GET request on it using Postman.

[This guide](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/php-laravel) says just add this header `authorization": "Bearer YOUR_ID_TOKEN_HERE"`

I did but I always get `Unauthorized User`

Answer (score 0):

tried to tinker and found out it's looking for `config('laravel-auth0.secret_base64_encoded')`

tried to `use` this and manually execute the `$verifier->verifyAndDecode($encUser);`

but before that, i set `secret_base64_encoded` to false and it worked!

**EDIT: The seed project on their quickstart is OLD find the new one**